# Wifi Direct createGroup not working on some Samsung Phones (S7, A5 etc)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I want to get an Access point out of my android mobile device so that a legacy device can connect to the mobile device. To do this I use the createGroup API [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#createGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)] as in the example [https://github.com/DrJukka/MyWifiMesh]

It works perfectly fine in quite a few devices, however I see that on some Samsung devices like S7 Edge, A5 and others, the API returns success and it does give the SSID and password, however the legacy device cannot connect to those SSID and password (I think that it doesn't broadcast the SSID and password, it just gives a dummy SSID and password).

Has anybody encountered this issue before and is there a solution to this. Also, the issue is that it returns success, provides an Access point but no device can connect to the Access Point.